# Magento 1.9.2.0: Error with install Supee patch 11155?

Tags: magento-1.9

i install supee 11155 with version 1.9.2.0 but it failed. Does anyone know how to solve problems that can point me?

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-11155_CE_1.9.2.0_v4-2019-08-01-04-02-09.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 814 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Api/Role/Grid/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Queue/Preview.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Template/Preview.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Role/Grid/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Creditmemo/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Invoice/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Header.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Creditmemo/Create.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Invoice/Create.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Shipment/Create.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Transactions/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template/Preview.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Baseurl.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Locale.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized/Array.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Checkout/AgreementController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Email/TemplateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Compiler/Model/Process.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/AvailablePath.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CurrencySymbol/Model/System/Currencysymbol.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Coupon/Massgenerator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Report/Rule/Createdat.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/etc/system.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/configurable.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/currencysymbol/grid.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/addresses.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/window.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/currency/rate/matrix.phtml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sitemap.csv
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js
checking file js/tiny_mce/plugins/media/js/media.js
Hunk #1 FAILED at 483 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file js/varien/js.js
Hunk #1 FAILED at 707.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```